# postgresql query with AND / OR / UNION

Tags: postgresql

I'm having trouble with an 'advanced' (by my standards) query in Postgresql, and I'm not sure how I should be looking for the answer (keywords etc.). I have looked through the examples in the Postgresql handbook and searched stackOverflow for similar threads, but to no avail...

I have two tables: one with bills and one with transactions, and the table I would like to output contains only those transactions that are 1) more recent than the bill, 2) lower than or equal to the bill 3) on a specific account OR paid in cash.

This query does just that, but I guess it can be optimized:

```
((SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE amount = to_number('$bill_amount','99999999D99')
AND acc_int = 'cash'
AND date > to_date('$bill_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
UNION
(SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE amount = to_number('$bill_amount','99999999D99')
AND acc_int = 'xxx-xxxxxxx-xx'
AND date > to_date('$bill_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
ORDER BY date DESC)
UNION
((SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE amount < to_number('$bill_amount','99999999D99')
AND acc_int = 'cash'
AND date > to_date('$bill_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
UNION
(SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE amount < to_number('$bill_amount','99999999D99')
AND acc_int = 'xxx-xxxxxxx-xx'
AND date > to_date('$bill_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
ORDER BY date DESC)
```

The first two selects could be merged if I could simply add an `OR` to the 'acc_int'-condition without upsetting the other conditions. I thought this should be done by using brackets, but it didn't seem to work.

Furthermore I would like to sort the result so that first all transactions that equal the amount on the bill and then, by date, the lower amounts - that's why I combine the first two selects with the last two selects but using `UNION` seems to upset the ordering.

THX for any insight (answers or links to good resources are both welcome!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete query could look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   transactions 
WHERE  amount <= to_number('$bill_amount','99999999D99')
AND    acc_int IN ('cash', 'xxx-xxxxxxx-xx')
AND    date > to_date('$bill_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER  BY
      (amount <> to_number('$bill_amount','99999999D99'))
     , date DESC
```

- `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`, that's why I have the `<>` operator in the `ORDER BY` expression.
- Be aware that in your original query [`UNION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION) removes duplicate rows. If you don't have complete duplicates in your table, the result is the same (and `UNION ALL` would have been the better choice to begin with). If you do, add a `DISTINCT` clause:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT * ...
  ```
- You write that `OR` didn't seem to work for you. But it should. This ..

  ```
  AND    acc_int IN ('cash', 'xxx-xxxxxxx-xx')
  ```

  .. is exactly equivalent to:

  ```
  AND   (acc_int = 'cash' OR acc_int = 'xxx-xxxxxxx-xx')
  ```

In fact the query planner rewrites the first form into the second.

Comment: THX - this is the one - it works perfectly. I knew it could be done, but was held back by 1 bug (the OR-clause was probably miswritten, because I think I tried it the way you describe) and 1 thing I didn't even know (expressions in the ORDER BY-instruction).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE amount <= to_number('$bill_amount','99999999D99')
AND acc_int IN ('cash', 'xxx-xxxxxxx-xx')
AND date = to_date('$bill_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you - your answer has effectively cut down the query in half (the amount-condition being altered to 'WHERE amount BETWEEN 0 AND $bill_amount' to avoid negative results. The only remaining question is the one about the sorting order: exact amount-matches on top and lower/partial amounts below.

Comment: You can order by amount, also.

Comment: Yes, I knew that and I totally forgot about it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: +1 Except for the typo in `date = to_date ..` (must be `>`) and the `ORDER BY`, you caught the essence.